# Iframe header location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, drop-down-menu

I've a problem with iframe. My first file filtre.html contain iframe with a basic code like this:

```
<iframe name="filtre_demo" src="http://localhost:8888/modules/filtredemo/filtre.php" scrolling="no" height="220" width="220" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

This file filtre.php is a drop down dynamic list with 3 levels (PHP/MYSQL).

Filtre.php this file is actually a dynamic dropdown 3 levels and will find info in a DB. The submit sent to a URL and all working fine.

My problem is with iframe. When I click on submit, target page is found in this part of 220x220 instead of reloading the parent page.

I tried several solutions to no avail. Here is part of my php file (I deliberately truncated several parts) including the header location and the form:

```
     $ligne=mysql_fetch_assoc($rech_lien);
     $lien=$ligne['lien'];
     header('Location:'.$lien.'');

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
<head>
</head>
<body style="font-size: 75%; width: 210px;">

<form action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="chgcategories">

<fieldset style="border: 0px">
    <select name="modele" id="modele" onchange="submit();">
        <option value="-1">-Choisissez un modele-</option>
                <select name="sous_categorie" id="sous_categorie">
                    <option value="-1">-Sous-cat-</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="nb_listes"  value="3" />
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok2" value="Envoyer"/>
</form>
```

I also tried with javascript but without success. In this configuration there I removed the line:

```
header('Location:'.$lien.'');
```

Here is the javascript code in the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.document.location.href="<?php echo $lien; ?>";
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-size: 75%; width: 210px;">
```

The problems in this case is that the document load loop.

Anyway, I'm stuck, I thank you in advance for your help.

Vincent

Comment: `<form target="_parent" ...>`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what's happening, the buttons are targeting the contents of the iframe and loading the page inside that, instead of the actual window?  If that's the case, set the `target` attribute the either `_parent` or `_top` and that should target the actual window.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply but I already tried. The problem is: when I select an option in my first dropdown list, the target executes immediately and not at the end when validation submit.

Comment: That will be from this line: `<select name="modele" id="modele" onchange="submit();">` - this will submit the form after the dropdown changes, and not wait for you click the submit button.  Remove the 'onchange' if you don't want that behavior.

Comment: thank you but if I delete this element onchange, without this setting my module will not work.

Comment: the `onChange="submit();"` attribute is what is causing the form to be submitted when you select an option in the dropdown.  Translated to English, it means "when the value of this dropdown changes, submit the form it is a part of."

Answer (score 0):

You can try this javascript code:

`<?php`

`/*-------Your Php Code-----*/`

`\\Replace this code @header(location)`

`echo "<script>";`

`echo "window.location='yourloation.php';";`

`echo "</script>";`

`/*-------Your Php Code-----*/`

`?>`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, but now with this solution I've got another problem
  echo "<script>";
  echo "window.location='$lien'";
  echo "</script>";

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /site/shop/modules/filtre/.http://www.site.com/shop/84-test. on this server.

Comment: I solved this access problem. But my result is always displayed in my iframe and does not reload my parent page.

Comment: <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.href = "example3.php?class=' . $_GET['classid'] . '"; </script>' ?>